# Laravel API call data not returning as expected on remote server but working fine on local machine

Tags: laravel, api, vuejs2, axios

I'm making an API call to a Laravel route which returns data from a service desk API.

I make a POST from Axios in my Vue component and my route sits in the middle, delivering the result back to my page.

```
axios({
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/getTickets',
            data:
            {
                sort: this.serverParams.sort,
                status: this.serverParams.status,
                ticketsPageNumber: this.serverParams.ticketsPageNumber,
                ticketsPerPage: this.serverParams.ticketsPerPage,
                userEmail: this.contactDetails["email"],
                ticketsVisibility: this.groupTicketAccess,
                userGroup: this.groupName,
                filters: this.serverParams.columnFilters,
                searchTerm: this.serverParams.searchTerm,
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.totalRecords = response.data.page_info.last_index;
            this.rows = response.data.data;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false, this.hidden = false))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ' + error)
        });
```

Everything works fine locally, which suggests to me that this is some kind of backend issue, but having spent the better half of a day attempting to correct the issue - i simply am struggling.

On my local instance, the logic returns the data from the third party API and so allows response.data.page_info.last_index to be returned into the Vue data value this.totalRecords.
However, on the remote server, although the data is returned (i can see it in the network response tab as below), the data tab is simply not seeming to work as intended. It looks almost as if the data is returned as JSON, but not being recognised as an object??

[Local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VieFo.png)

[Remote Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhg2.png)

What is odd to me, is that when viewing the HXR response in Chrome's network tools, on the remote server, it seems to be adding a snippet of the request payload at the top of the response.

[Local Machine - Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6l2f.png)
[Remote Server - Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV5eU.png)

Has anyone experienced something like this that is able to assist? The logic is identical on both machines so i'm at a complete loss as to why it would be behaving this way.

Finally, here is the logic that returns the data from the third party API, using the Guzzle library.

```
public function search($URI, $auth, $query)
{
    $response = self::$client->get($URI, [
        'http_errors' => false,
        'auth' => $auth,
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    return $this->validateResponse($response);
}
```